# Mapping a function on the values of a map in Clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, map-function

I want to transform one map of values to another map with the same keys but with a function applied to the values. I would think there was a function for doing this in the clojure api, but I have been unable to find it.

Here's an example implementation of what I'm looking for

```
(defn map-function-on-map-vals [m f]
  (reduce (fn [altered-map [k v]] (assoc altered-map k (f v))) {} m))
(println (map-function-on-map-vals {:a "test" :b "testing"} #(.toUpperCase %)))
{:b TESTING, :a TEST}
```

Does anybody know if `map-function-on-map-vals` already exists? I would think it did (probably with a nicer name too).

Answer (score 174, accepted):

I like your `reduce` version just fine.  I think it's idiomatic.  Here's a version using list comprehension anyways.

```
(defn foo [m f]
  (into {} (for [[k v] m] [k (f v)])))
```

Comment: I like this version because it's super short and obvious if you understand all the functions and such it uses.  And if you don't it's an excuse to learn them!

Comment: I agree. I didn't know the into function, but it makes perfect sense using it here.

Comment: Oh man you hadn't seen into?  You are in for a treat.  I abuse the hell out of that function every chance I get.  So powerful and useful.

Comment: Nope.  Neither are `hash-map` or `zipmap` or `merge` or `reduce`.

Comment: btw, the [source code for `fmap`](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic/blob/aa028f7467d193a5cfad0626b324f4c682b91c15/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/generic/functor.clj#L19)  (see Arthur Edelstein's answer), when used on a Clojure map, is essentially the same as this answer.

Comment: I like it, but is there any reason for the arguments order (besides the question) ? I was expecting [f m] as in `map` for some reason.

Comment: I strongly recommend to use (empty m) rather then {}. So it would keep being a particular type of map.

Comment: I haven't read the reduce one but this looks so cool.

Answer (score 101):

You can use the [`clojure.algo.generic.functor/fmap`](https://clojure.github.io/algo.generic/clojure.algo.generic.functor-api.html#clojure.algo.generic.functor/fmap):

```
user=> (use '[clojure.algo.generic.functor :only (fmap)])
nil
user=> (fmap inc {:a 1 :b 3 :c 5})
{:a 2, :b 4, :c 6}
```

Comment: I know this answer was a bit late looking at the dates, but I reckon it is spot on.

Comment: Did this make it into clojure 1.3.0?

Comment: the generic.function lib has moved to a separate library:
    `org.clojure/algo.generic "0.1.0"`

the example should now read:

    `(use '[clojure.algo.generic.functor :only (fmap)])
    (fmap inc {:a 1 :b 3 :c 5})`

Comment: Any idea how to do find `fmap` in ClojureScript?

Answer (score 43):

Here is a fairly typical way to transform a map.
 `zipmap`  takes a list of keys and a list of values and "does the right thing" producing a new Clojure map. You could also put the `map` around the keys to change them, or both.

```
(zipmap (keys data) (map #(do-stuff %) (vals data)))
```

or to wrap it up in your function:

```
(defn map-function-on-map-vals [m f]
    (zipmap (keys m) (map f (vals m))))
```

Comment: It irritates me that I have to supply the keys for it, but it's not a high price to pay. It definitely looks a lot nicer than my original suggestion.

Comment: Are we guaranteed that keys and vals return the corresponding values in the same order?  For both sorted maps and hash maps?

Comment: Rob: yes, keys and vals will use the same order for all maps -- the same order as a seq on the map uses.  Since hash, sorted, and array maps are all immutable, there's no chance of the order changing in the mean time.

Comment: That does seem to be the case, but is it documented anywhere? At least the docstrings for keys and vals fail to mention this. I would be more comfortable using this if I could point to some official documentation that promises it's going to work.

Comment: The function example should have `(vals m)`

Comment: @JouniK.Seppänen, I share your concern and in fact it is documented in vals and keys that the order is the same as seq. Doc for `vals`: "Returns a sequence of the map's values, in the same order as (seq map)." Doc for `keys`: "Returns a sequence of the map's keys, in the same order as (seq map)." The links where I got those are https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/vals and https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keys, respectively.

Comment: @Jason Yeah, they added this to the documentation in version 1.6 I think. http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-1302

Comment: Typo in the first code snippet: one paren after `do-stuff %)` should be moved to the end of the line.

Comment: Thanks @AhmedFasih that mistake has been sitting there for more then 7 years! (And you are free to edit these things directly as well)

Comment: Thank you, got it! My thinking for not making the edit directly was this: it’d go to peer review, and most would feel uncomfortable reviewing such a subtle change in an admittedly unusual language—some might suspect I was vandalizing… So I pinged you  if you hadn’t responded, I’d probably have risked an edit !

Answer (score 26):

Taken from the Clojure Cookbook, there is reduce-kv:

```
(defn map-kv [m f]
  (reduce-kv #(assoc %1 %2 (f %3)) {} m))
```

Answer (score 24):

**Clojure 1.11** added a function for this to `clojure.core`, the standard library. Clojure 1.11 was released [on 2022-03-22](https://clojure.org/news/2022/03/22/clojure-1-11-0).

### [`update-vals`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/update-vals)

`(update-vals m f)` applies the function to every value in the map. It returns a new map `{k (f v) ...}`.

#### Usage

```clj
(update-vals {:a 1 :b 2} str)
;;        => {:a "1", :b "2"}
```

---

### *See also:* [`update-keys`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/update-keys)

`(update-keys m f)` applies the function to every key in the map. It returns a new map `{(f k) v ...}`. All keys resulting from `(f k)` must be unique.

This function, too, was added in Clojure 1.11.

#### Usage

```clj
(update-keys {:a 1 :b 2} str)
;;        => {":a" 1, ":b" 2}
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a fairly idiomatic way to do this:

```
(defn map-function-on-map-vals [m f]
        (apply merge
               (map (fn [[k v]] {k (f v)})
                    m)))
```

Example:

```
user> (map-function-on-map-vals {1 1, 2 2, 3 3} inc))
{3 4, 2 3, 1 2}
```

Comment: If it isn't clear: the anon function *destructures* the key and value to *k* and *v* and then returns a hash-map mapping *k* to *(f v)*.

Answer (score 6):

## `map-map`, `map-map-keys`, and `map-map-values`

I know of no existing function in Clojure for this, but here’s an implementation of that function as `map-map-values` that you are free to copy. It comes with two closely related functions, `map-map` and `map-map-keys`, which are also missing from the standard library:

```
(defn map-map
    "Returns a new map with each key-value pair in `m` transformed by `f`. `f` takes the arguments `[key value]` and should return a value castable to a map entry, such as `{transformed-key transformed-value}`."
    [f m]
    (into (empty m) (map #(apply f %) m)) )

(defn map-map-keys [f m]
    (map-map (fn [key value] {(f key) value}) m) )

(defn map-map-values [f m]
    (map-map (fn [key value] {key (f value)}) m) )
```

### Usage

You can call `map-map-values` like this:

```
(map-map-values str {:a 1 :b 2})
;;           => {:a "1", :b "2"}
```

And the other two functions like this:

```
(map-map-keys str {:a 1 :b 2})
;;         => {":a" 1, ":b" 2}
(map-map (fn [k v] {v k}) {:a 1 :b 2})
;;    => {1 :a, 2 :b}
```

### Alternative implementations

If you only want `map-map-keys` or `map-map-values`, without the more general `map-map` function, you can use these implementations, which don’t rely on `map-map`:

```
(defn map-map-keys [f m]
    (into (empty m)
        (for [[key value] m]
            {(f key) value} )))

(defn map-map-values [f m]
    (into (empty m)
        (for [[key value] m]
            {key (f value)} )))
```

Also, here’s an alternative implementation of `map-map` that is based on [`clojure.walk/walk`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.walk/walk) instead of [`into`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/into), if you prefer this phrasing:

```
(defn map-map [f m]
    (clojure.walk/walk #(apply f %) identity m) )
```

### Parellel versions – `pmap-map`, etc.

There are also parallel versions of these functions if you need them. They simply use [`pmap`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/pmap) instead of [`map`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/map).

```
(defn pmap-map [f m]
    (into (empty m) (pmap #(apply f %) m)) )
(defn pmap-map-keys [f m]
    (pmap-map (fn [key value] {(f key) value}) m) )
(defn pmap-map-values [f m]
    (pmap-map (fn [key value] {key (f value)}) m) )
```

Comment: Also check prismatics map-vals function. It's faster using transients https://github.com/Prismatic/plumbing/blob/4b01888d23cd99e02a32c61ee6ff23b22edcfcfd/src/plumbing/core.clj#L33

Answer (score 2):

I'm a Clojure n00b, so there may well be much more elegant solutions. Here's mine:

```
(def example {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4})
(def func #(* % %))

(prn example)

(defn remap [m f]
  (apply hash-map (mapcat #(list % (f (% m))) (keys m))))

(prn (remap example func))
```

The anon func makes a little 2-list from each key and its f'ed value. Mapcat runs this function over the sequence of the map's keys and concatenates the whole works into one big list. "apply hash-map" creates a new map from that sequence. The (% m) may look a little weird, it's idiomatic Clojure for applying a key to a map to look up the associated value.

Most highly recommended reading: The [Clojure Cheat Sheet](http://clojure.org/cheatsheet) .

Comment: I thought about going trough sequences as you've done in your example. I also like the name of you're function much more than my own :)

Comment: In Clojure, keywords are functions that look themselves up in whatever sequence is passed to them. That's why (:keyword a-map) works. But using the key as a function to look itself up in a map doesn't work if the key is not a keyword. So you might want to change the (% m) above to (m %) which will work no matter what the keys are.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for the tip, Siddhartha!

Answer (score 2):

I like your `reduce` version. With a very slight variation, it can also retain the type of records structures:

```
(defn map-function-on-map-vals [m f]
  (reduce (fn [altered-map [k v]] (assoc altered-map k (f v))) m m))
```

The `{}` was replaced by `m`. With that change, records remain records:

```
(defrecord Person [firstname lastname])

(def p (map->Person {}))
(class p) '=> Person

(class (map-function-on-map-vals p
  (fn [v] (str v)))) '=> Person
```

By starting with `{}`, the record loses its *recordiness*, which one might want to retain, if you desire the record capabilities (compact memory representation for instance).

Answer (score 2):

```
(defn map-vals
  "Map f over every value of m.
   Returns a map with the same keys as m, where each of its values is now the result of applying f to them one by one.
   f is a function of one arg, which will be called which each value of m, and should return the new value.
   Faster then map-vals-transient on small maps (8 elements and under)"
  [f m]
  (reduce-kv (fn [m k v]
               (assoc m k (f v)))
             {} m))

(defn map-vals-transient
  "Map f over every value of m.
   Returns a map with the same keys as m, where each of its values is now the result of applying f to them one by one.
   f is a function of one arg, which will be called which each value of m, and should return the new value.
   Faster then map-vals on big maps (9 elements or more)"
  [f m]
  (persistent! (reduce-kv (fn [m k v]
                            (assoc! m k (f v)))
                          (transient {}) m)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why nobody has mentioned the [**specter**](https://github.com/redplanetlabs/specter) library yet.  It has been written to make this kind of transform easy to code (and, even more important, the written code easy to understand), while still being very performant:

```
(require '[com.rpl.specter :as specter])

(defn map-vals [m f]
  (specter/transform
   [specter/ALL specter/LAST]
   f m))

(map-vals {:a "test" :b "testing"}
          #(.toUpperCase %))
```

Writing such a function in pure Clojure is simple, but the code gets much trickier once you move on to highly nested code composed of different data structures.  And this is where **specter** comes in.

I recommend watching [this episode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTCy_DkAJGk) on Clojure TV which explains the motivation behind and details of **specter**.

Answer (score 0):

Clojure 1.7 ([released](https://clojure.org/news/2015/06/30/clojure-17) June 30, 2015) provides an elegant solution for this with [`update`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update):

```clj
(defn map-function-on-map-vals [m f]
    (->> (map #(update % 1 f) m)
         (into {})))

(map-function-on-map-vals {:a "test" :b "testing"} #(.toUpperCase %))
;; => {:a "TEST", :b "TESTING"}
```

Comment: This returns a seq not a hash-map