# applying function in a map to each value in a map based on its key

Tags: clojure

Suppose I have a map:

```
{:name "foo"
 :age "bar"}
```

And another one

```
{:name (fn [val] (println val))
 :age (fn [val] (= val "bar"))}
```

I want to apply function keyed by `:name` on second map to the first map, which also keyed by `:name` and the function keyed by `:age` to the first map which keyed by `:age`. How to do this the clojure way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use merge-with

```
(def m1 {:name "foo"
         :age "bar"})

(def m2 {:name (fn [val] (println val))
         :age (fn [val] (= val "bar"))})

user=> (merge-with #(%1 %2) m2 m1)
foo
{:name nil, :age true}
```

Comment: This is concise, but only works if the two maps have exactly the same keys, which isn't really clear from the question.

Comment: @amalloy Thanks for clarification, I found it's a great usage example for a *rare* used function.

Answer (score 1):

`map` over one map and get corresponding function from the other one.

```
(def m1 {:name "foo"
         :age "bar"})

(def m2 {:name (fn [val] (println val))
         :age (fn [val] (= val "bar"))})

(map (fn [[k v]]
       ((get m2 k) v)) 
     m1)
```

Each iteration over the map passes a vector to the function, in your sample:

```
[:name "foo"]
[:age "bar"]
```

So destructuring the function parameter into `[[k v]]` gives you each key/value separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
(def data { :name "don knotts" 
        :dob "1/1/1940" 
        :cob "Valdosta"  })

(def fxns {:name identity :dob identity :cob clojure.string/reverse})

(defn bmap [data fxn]
  (apply merge (for [[k1 d] data [k2 f] fxn  :when (= k1 k2)]
     {k1 (f d)})))

;=user>{:cob "atsodlaV", :dob "1/1/1940", :name "don knotts"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this, if you need more resilience:

```
(defn fmm [m fm]
  (let [f (fn [k] ((get fm k identity) (k m)))
        ks (keys m)]
    (zipmap ks (map f ks))))
```

Comment: Also, check out the answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676891/mapping-a-function-on-the-values-of-a-map-in-clojure?rq=1)