# Update values in a vector of maps in clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure, update-in

I have a vector of maps with same keys:

```
(def items [{:id 1 :name "first item"}
            {:id 2 :name "second item"}])
```

I can uppercase the value of the `:name` key in the first map in the vector:

```
(update-in items [0 :name] clojure.string/upper-case)
=> [{:id 1, :name "FIRST ITEM"} {:id 2, :name "second item"}]
```

How can I uppercase every `:name` key in every map? I expect this:

```
[{:id 1, :name "FIRST ITEM"} {:id 2, :name "SECOND ITEM"}]
```

Comment: Similar useful questions http://stackoverflow.com/q/22359975 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1676891.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
(map #(update-in % [:name] clojure.string/upper-case) items)
```

The % sign stands in for each map in `items` in the function expression.

Comment: If you're using Clojure 1.7, you could use [`update`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update) instead of `update-in`.