# use 'for' inside 'let' return a list of hash-map

Tags: clojure

Sorry for the bad title 'cause I don't know how to describe in 10 words. Here's the detail:

I'd like to loop a file in format like:

> a:1 b:2...

I want to loop each line, collect all 'k:v' into a hash-map.

> { a 1, b 2...}

I initialize a hash-map in a 'let' form, then loop all lines with 'for' inside let form.
In each loop step, I use 'assoc' to update the **original hash-map**.

> (let [myhash {}]
>
> (for [line #{"A:1 B:2" "C:3 D:4"}
>
> ```
>    :let [pairs (clojure.string/split line #"\s")]]
> ```
>
> (for [[k v] (map #(clojure.string/split %1 #":") pairs)]
>
> ```
>  (assoc myhash k (Float. v)))))
> ```

But in the end I got a lazy-seq of hash-map, like this:

> { {a 1, b 2...}  {x 98 y 99 z 100 ...} }

I know how to 'merge' the result now, but still don't understand why 'for' inside 'let' return
a list of result.

*What I'm confused is: does the 'myhash' in the inner 'for' refers to the 'myhash' declared in the 'let' form every time? If I do want a list of hash-map like the output, is this the idiomatic way in Clojure ?*

Answer (score 2):

Clojure "for" is a [list comprehension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension), so it creates list. It is NOT a for loop. 
Also, you seem to be trying to modify the myhash, but Clojure's datastructures are immutable.
The way I would approach the problem is to try to create a list of pair like (["a" 1] ["b" 2] ..) and the use the (into {} the-list-of-pairs)

Comment: Thank you dAni. I like Python's list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

If the file format is really as simple as you're describing, then something much more simple should suffice:

```
(apply hash-map (re-seq #"\w+" (slurp "your-file.txt")))
```

I think it's more readable if you use the [`->>` threading macro](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/-%3E%3E):

```
(->> "your-file.txt" slurp (re-seq #"\w+") (apply hash-map))
```

The slurp function reads an entire file into a string. The `re-seq` function will just return a sequence of all the words in your file (basically the same as splitting on spaces and colons in this case). Now you have a sequence of alternating key-value pairs, which is exactly what `hash-map` expects...

I know this doesn't really answer your question, but you did ask about more idiomatic solutions.

I think @dAni is right, and you're confused about some fundamental concepts of Clojure (e.g. the immutable collections). I'd recommend working through some of the exercises on [4Clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/) as a fun way to get more familiar with the language. Each time you solve a problem, you can compare your own solution to others' solutions and see other (possibly more idomatic) ways to solve the problem.

---

Sorry, I didn't read your code very thorougly last night when I was posting my answer. I just realized you actually convert the values to Floats. Here are a few options.

1) `partition` the sequence of inputs into key/val pairs so that you can `map` over it. Since you now how a sequence of pairs, you can use `into` to add them all to a map.

```
(->> "kvs.txt" slurp (re-seq #"\w") (partition 2)
     (map (fn [[k v]] [k (Float. v)])) (into {}))
```

2) Declare an [auxiliary map-values function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1676891/1427124) for maps and use that on the result:

```
(defn map-values [m f]
  (into {} (for [[k v] m] [k (f v)])))

(->> "your-file.txt" slurp (re-seq #"\w+")
     (apply hash-map) (map-values #(Float. %)))
```

3) If you don't mind having symbol keys instead of strings, you can safely use the Clojure reader to convert all your keys and values.

```
(->> "your-file.txt" slurp (re-seq #"\w+")
     (map read-string) (apply hash-map))
```

Note that this is a safe use of [`read-string`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/read-string) because our call to `re-seq` would filter out any hazardous input. However, this will give you longs instead of floats since numbers like `1` are long integers in Clojure

Answer (score 0):

*Does the `myhash` in the inner `for` refer to the `myhash` declared in the `let` form every time?*

Yes.

- The `let` binds `myhash` to `{}`, and it is never rebound. `myhash` is always `{}`.
- `assoc` *returns* a modified map, but does not alter `myhash`.

So the code can be reduced to

```
(for [line ["A:1 B:2" "C:3 D:4"]
      :let [pairs (clojure.string/split line #"\s")]]
  (for [[k v] (map #(clojure.string/split %1 #":") pairs)]
    (assoc {} k (Float. v))))
```

... which produces the same result:

```
(({"A" 1.0} {"B" 2.0}) ({"C" 3.0} {"D" 4.0}))
```

*If I do want a list of hash-map like the output, is this the idiomatic way in Clojure?*

No.

See [@DaoWen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25102129/1562315).